# Why can't I use any DOM functions?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<style  type="text/css">
div.main1{
background-color:#EEE;
border: 2px dotted;
padding: 5px;
}
div.sub{
background-color:#DDD;
border: 1px dashed;
padding: 3px;
width:50%;
}
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showOptions(box){
box.childNodes[0].style.visibilty = "visible";
box.childNodes[1].style.visibilty = "visible";
}

function hideOptions(box){
box.childNodes[0].style.visibilty = "hidden";
box.childNodes[1].style.visibilty = "hidden";
}
</script>
<center>

<div class="main1">
<div class="sub" onmouseover="showOptions(this);" onmouseout="hideOptions(this);"><input />               
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is an example of the code I am using, i am using Dreamweaver... My concern is that When i Ctrl + Space after "box" in the showOptions(box) method, i don't see any of the DOM object options, i apologise if i'm making no sense because im quite new to HTML + Javascript, basically what im trying to do is check if the given argument to the function of a HTML Element, and if so, allow me to access its methods such as "childNodes" or "setAttribute()" and so on..

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this question about code hinting in Dreamweaver? Or is it about how  to ensure `box` is an HTML Element before operating on it?

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` tag, and your `.sub` only has one element child, so I'm not sure what you expect of `.childNodes[1]`.

Comment: Just to be clear, there's no bug, right? You're only asking about the IDE suggesting methods based on the type? If that's so, it's a not a good fit for SO, SO is for fixing code that doesn't work.

Comment: @JuanMendes - I think it's a little of A and a little of B. Mainly the IDE though we're seeing all other probs too :)

Comment: @Darren We? You work with Shaun? If you're getting an error, please don't keep that a secret, and don't post two questions as one

Comment: @JuanMendes - nope, don't know him. Meant we as in SO members reading this post

Comment: @Darren I prefer to focus on the question, and I'd prefer if you let Shaun clarify what he wants out of the question

Comment: It's fine, i'll just do a bit of blind typing, It all works fine :)

Comment: it's not `visibilty` - it is `visibility`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is called Intellisense/code hinting. From what I understand, Dreamweaver doesn't do a very good job with this.

have you thought about using a different editor? If you're working with mainly code other than .Net then maybe something like [Komodo Edit](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products).

If you're going down the .Net route then there is of course [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) which does a much better job with Intellisense/code hinting

**Edit**

Also, you're attempting to see the intellisense on the method itself - this isn't the intention. It's intended to look AT the method from somewhere else. So ideally you would do your CTRL+space where shown below:

```
    onmouseover="showOptions(this);"
    -------------------------^Here
```

**Another Edit**

Also, looking at your code, it's not going to work..

You are referencing a child that doesn't exist:

```
box.childNodes[1].style.visibilty = "hidden";
```

childNodes starts at zero, so `[0]` would be the `input`. `[1]` is nothing.

**Finally**

Might I suggest you install [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and Firebug. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will help you debug all your javascript. It does a GREAT job of telling you what/where the issue is.

Comment: The best "intellisense" for JS/DOM is WebStorm (and its cousins) but it isn't free. Aptana (which is free) is pretty good. Yuck, who develops JS with Visual Studio?

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if i could stick to DreamWeaver, and if i try and actually run the above code it doesn't actually work, so i don't think its all a IDE problem.. If you think about it, how will the dreamweaver know what the type of argument passed in will be considering that javascript data types aren't static? is there like a check i can do?

Comment: @ShaunWild It is true that there's no guarantee since it's loosely typed, but the better IDEs take educated guesses which work well if you write OO JS, and often infer types from JsDoc http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReference

Comment: Is there no kind of "instanceof" check i could do, then declare a new object with a type cast?

Comment: @ShaunWild. Might I suggest installing Firefox and Firebug. Firebug will help you debug Javascript and it will tell you exactly where and what the error is

Comment: And to your edit there were two span tags, corresponding for each one, after the input but the stackoverflow editor removed them for some reason.

Comment: var x = (HTMLElement) box;
Is there no way i can do something like that?

Comment: Sorry, That question is wandering off the scope of this one. you'll need to ask a new one with code examples.

Comment: @ShaunWild Why would you need that? JS is loosely typed, if it quacks like a duck

Answer (score 0):

You can give the IDE hints about types with JSDOC

```
/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} box
 */
function showOptions(box){

}
```

Many IDEs are able to read that information and provide the correct methods for an HTMLElement. However, I haven't seen one that is smart enough to know what to suggest if you hit ctrl+space after `box.childNodes[i]`